# putting the checkboxes values in arrays without ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have some checkboxes:-

```
<label>CHANNELS</label>
   <md-checkbox  ng-model="channel[0]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(channel[0]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(channel[0])" value="channel[0]">CHANNEL A</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="channel[1]" class="margin-left-1 md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(channel[1]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(channel[1])" value="channel[1]">CHANNEL B</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="channel[2]" class="margin-left-1 md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(channel[2]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(channel[2])" value="channel[2]">CHANNEL C</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="channel[3]" class="margin-left-1 md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(channel[3]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(channel[3])" value="channel[3]">CHANNEL D</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="channel[4]" class="margin-left-1 md-primary md-hue-2" ng-checked="selected.indexOf(channel[4]) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(channel[4])" value="channel[4]">CHANNEL E</md-checkbox>
```

I am trying to put the values in an array.
My directive code is:-

```
scope.channels = ['CHANNEL A','CHANNEL B','CHANNEL C','CHANNEL D','CHANNEL E'];
                     scope.selected = [];

             scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(channel) {
              console.log(channel);
               var idx = scope.selected.indexOf(channel);
                     console.log(idx);
               if (idx > -1) {
                 scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
               }

               else {
                 scope.selected.push(channel);
               }
             };
```

I know by using ng-repeat it will work better but by using that I have some other css issues which is difficult to correct.I only want this method to be work. Can any one tell me how I can I make it work without using ng-repeat.

Comment: You should post a question regarding the css issues as there's really no reason you should be doing this without ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also recommend making ngRepeat work, but to answer the question asked...

Don't use ngModel and ngChecked together.

Try this:

```
<label>CHANNELS</label>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[0]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="channel[0]" ng-false-value="null">CHANNEL A</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[1]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="channel[1]" ng-false-value="null">CHANNEL B</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[2]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="channel[2]" ng-false-value="null">CHANNEL C</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[3]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="channel[3]" ng-false-value="null">CHANNEL D</md-checkbox>
   <md-checkbox ng-model="selected[4]" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-true-value="channel[4]" ng-false-value="null">CHANNEL E</md-checkbox>
```

This will set the values of the `selected` array to the corresponding value of the `channel` array if the box is checked. Note: You can't use `selected.length` to determine if anything is checked because the `selected` array will always have 4 members, some of which may be null.

Comment: Is there any way to not select false value to that model array. Only make an array of selected checkbox value.

Comment: Just filter the array before you use it. `selected.filter(function(value){return !!value;})`